# Reading only particular column(s) from a text file into array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

Input file log.txt

```
--- Iteration      1(  37)  --

--- Iteration      1(  38)  --

--- Iteration      1(  39)  --

--- Iteration      2(   1)  --

--- Iteration      2(   2)  --

--- Iteration      2(   3)  --
```

Expected output; array1 [1 1 1 2 2 2] and array2 [37 38 39 1 2 3]

Is there any command where I can specify particular column(identified by column number) to be read into array for first column and particular column range(identified by column number range) to be read into second array for second column.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus I tried using mapfile but I am not able to implement it. thanks.

Comment: @j1-lee the command 'readarray -t ionic < <(cut -c 54-56 iter.txt)' is working fine when I manually enter it in command line but when I put it into shell script it through following error "TEST.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
TEST.sh: line 4: `readarray -t ionic < <(cut -c 54-56 iter.txt)'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
a1=(); a2=()
while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ([0-9]+)\(\ +([0-9]+) ]]; then
    a1+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
    a2+=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")
  fi
done < log.txt
declare -p a1 a2
```

Output:

```
declare -a a1=([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2" [4]="2" [5]="2")
declare -a a2=([0]="37" [1]="38" [2]="39" [3]="1" [4]="2" [5]="3")
```

I assume that log.txt does not contain any blank lines.